# Able to connect to Oracle 12c database using SQL*Plus, but not Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I installed Oracle Database 12c on my Windows 10. I was able to connect to database using SQL*Plus. I created a user named USER1 in SQL*Plus and granted full access. I tried to connect to the database using SQL Developer but got an error that says, "Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection". How can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot of Oracle SQL Developer]

None of similar old posts were helpful, so posting this question here.

---

More info:-
I named my database as kitab. I made sure that all oracle services are running:-
[image: Screenshot of running oracle services]

This is what it shows when I check the status of listener:-
[image: Status of Oracle Listener status]

This is the information from listener.ora:-
[image: Screenshot of listener.ora]

I changed SID to CLRExtProc and it gives me same error:-
[image: Another Screenshot of sql developer]

What else can I do to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Pretty sure your SID isn't XE. That's only for 11g Express Edition.

Comment: You are right. I tried with SID CLRExtProc, but it gives me same error. I added more info in my original post.

Comment: that's not it either - based on your listener setup, you don't have a database yet. did you use the database creation assistant (DBCA) to create a database?

Comment: Yes I used DBCA to create a database named kitab. And I am able to connect to kitab database in SQL Plus cmd. So what do I need to do to be able to connect through SQL developer?

Comment: then you should have a service running also called kitab - but you don't. the listener should have dynamically added it, but you may need to do so manually.

Comment: you can try the Bequeath connection type - it doesn't require the listener at all

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to:

- run "Services"

  - I don't have Windows 10, but - on Windows 7, you can find it by

    - typing "`services.msc`" into "Start - Search Programs and Files", or
    - in "Administrative tools" within the "Control Panel"
- check status of Oracle services

  - I presume not all of them are started up. If so,

    - start them up now, *manually*, and then try to establish connection with SQL Developer
    - change their startup mode to "automatic" so that they are started every time you power on the computer

Comment: I added more info in my post. Those are the services I see running. Am I missing any other necessary services?